# Please help me understand a sentence in Bishop's "Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning"

Tags: probability, distributions, classification, decision-theory

The sentence is in section 1.5.1 "Minimizing the misclassification rate" (page 39), underlined in red:

[image]

The author thinks this statement is "clear", but I just can't understand. Can you please help me understand it, preferably in rigorous math derivation? Thank you.

Comment: Consider this game: You get to choose one of two numbers.  You win when you choose the smaller.  Which do you choose?  Play this game for each $x$ in turn.  That's all this amounts to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My difficulties came from the settings/context of the text. Since the text explains what $\mathcal R_k$ are at the beginning of this section (in this paragraph, but not shown in the excerpt), I had thought that classification $\mathcal R_1, \mathcal R_2$ is pre-defined before calculating equation (1.78), and that then we assign $\mathbf x$ to class $\mathcal C_1$ or $\mathcal C_2$ freely, with this assignment being the variable of the minimization problem. It turns out that the classification of whether $\mathbf x$ belongs to $\mathcal R_1$ or $\mathcal R_2$ is unknown before equation (1.78). The underlined sentence actually defines a classification rule. Then, we can prove that this rule achieves a smaller $p$(mistake) than any other arbitrary classification. The proof is easy (as suggested by the starting word "Clearly"), but I still need to clarify the settings a little bit here: the assumed condition $p({\mathbf x},\mathcal C_1)>p({\mathbf x},\mathcal C_2)$ is pre-defined before calculating equation (1.78). It holds no matter how we assign $\mathbf x$. So, in the optimal assignment stated in the underlined text, $\mathbf x$ should be assigned to the first integral, i.e., $\mathcal R_1$, because $p({\mathbf x},\mathcal C_2)$ is smaller. In another arbitrary classification in which $\mathbf x\in\mathcal R_2$, we should look at the second integral in equation (1.78), where the term in the summation is $p(\mathbf x,\mathcal C_1)$. From the given condition $p(\mathbf x,\mathcal C_1)>p(\mathbf x,\mathcal C_2)$, this would result in a larger $p$(mistake).

Note that the assignment of an $\mathbf x$ can be either of the two classes with a probability. At first, I had thought the assignment is deterministic (white or black), which also caused my difficulty in understanding the text.

Comment: Is this intended as an answer to your own question, or is this intended to add additional contextual information to the question? Note that you should only use the Answer box to write answers; if you need to add more information to the question, you can click the Edit button below your question.